# Отправить placeholder переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```
 Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
        var code = result.codeResult.code;

        if (App.lastResult !== code) {
            App.lastResult = code;
            var $node = null, canvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.image;

            $node = $('<li><div class="thumbnail"><div class="imgWrapper"><img /></div><div class="caption"><h4 class="code"></h4></div></div></li>');
            $node.find("img").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL());
            $node.find("h4.code").html(code);

            $("#result_strip ul.thumbnails").prepend($node);
        }
```

в html выводится
в теги результат

```
<div id="result_strip">
        <ul class="thumbnails"></ul>
        <ul class="collector"></ul>
      </div>
```

здесь получается некое число

```
<h4 class="code">2423542355</h4>
```

сейчас хочу заменить h4 на `<input type="text" placeholder=></input>` что нужно поправить в строке `$node.find("h4.code").html(code);` чтоб в input был предварительное число?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $node = $('<li><div class="thumbnail"><div class="imgWrapper"><img /></div><div class="caption"><input type="text" class="code" placeholder=""></input></div></div></li>');
    $node.find("img").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL());
    $node.find("input.code").attr("placeholder", code);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('h4').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this)
  $this.replaceWith($('<input>').prop('placeholder', $this.text()))
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 class="code">2423542355</h4>
```